# validating a list of input variables in terraform

Tags: loops, iterator, terraform

This validation block works for a single input variable.

```
variable "mytestname" {

     validation {
        condition = length(regexall("test$", var.mytestname)) > 0
        error_message = "Should end in test"
     }
}
```

I need it to work inside a for_each - or have some workaround to accomplish this. The issue is that there is a restriction on the condition statement - the condition HAS to take in the input variable itself (i.e. - it cannot accept an each.value)

```
variable "mytestnames" {

listnames = split(",",var.mytestnames)     

for_each = var.listnames

     validation {
        condition = length(regexall("test$", each.value)) > 0
        error_message = "Should end in test"
      }
}
```

The above snippet does not work. I need a way I can iterate over a list of values and validate each of them. It looks like the newly introduced 'validation block' does not work on lists of input variables. There must be a way to do this without a validation block...??

Answer (score 1):

we can validate a loop

```
variable "mytestnames" {
  type        = string
  description = "comma separated list of names"
  # default     = "nametest,name1test,name2test"
  default = "nametest,nametest1,nametest2"

  validation {
    condition = alltrue([
      for n in split(",", var.mytestnames) :
      can(regex("test$", n)) # can't use a local var 'can only refer to the variable itself'
    ])
    error_message = "Should end in test" # can't use local var here either
  }
}
```

```bash
│ Error: Invalid value for variable
│ 
│   on main.tf line 5:
│    5: variable "mytestnames" {
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.mytestnames is "nametest,nametest1,nametest2"
│ 
│ Should end in test
│
```

... but, we can do better by using an output

```
locals { name_regex = "test$" }
output "mytestnames_valid" {
  value = "ok" # we can output whatever we want
  precondition {
    condition = alltrue([
      for n in split(",", var.mytestnames) :
      can(regex(local.name_regex, n)) # in an output we can use a local var
    ])
    error_message = format("invalid names: %s",
      join(",", [
        for n in split(",", var.mytestnames) :
        n if !can(regex(local.name_regex, n)) # we can reference local AND make a list of bad names
        ]
      )
    )
  }
}
```

```bash
│ Error: Module output value precondition failed
│ 
│   on main.tf line 23, in output "mytestnames":
│   23:     condition = alltrue([
│   24:       for n in split(",", var.mytestnames) :
│   25:       can(regex(local.name_regex, n)) # an an output we can use a local var
│   26:     ])
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.name_regex is "test$"
│     │ var.mytestnames is "nametest,nametest1,nametest2"
│ 
│ invalid names: nametest1,nametest2
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will not work. The attributes that can be defined in the variable block are type, description, and default. So how could we define additional attribute such as "listnames" dynamically...

```
variable "mytestnames" {
    listnames = split(",",var.mytestnames)
}
```

```
$ terraform validate

Error: Unsupported argument

  on hoge.tf line 3, in variable "mytestnames":
   3: listnames = split(",",var.mytestnames)

An argument named "listnames" is not expected here.
```

Comment: Yes - you are correct. The correct block is 

terraform {
  experiments = [variable_validation]
}

variable "list-names" {
 
type = list
default = ["example.com","www.example.com"]

     validation {
      condition = length(regexall("mytest.com$", var.list-names[0])) > 0
      error_message = "Should end in mytest.com."
    }
}